# recursively find out webpage video file url with wget or something like this

Tags: bash, wget, json, javascript, youtube

i'm trying to script a bash script which automatically can download video or audio files, maybe even "playlists" from youtube and other platforms like this. Especially the youtube video file url's are hard to get them, because they're encrypted in more than one javascript or json files. Maybe you know how hard it is to get the ending file pathes, but I really hope, somebody of you could tell me, how I can especially get those url's within a bash script using wget or something like that.
How can I find out automatically given file url's, even on youtube?

Thank you really much in forward guy's :)

Answer (score 0):

Since there are tools that already get the video from Youtube, you could read their source code to know how they do it, to reimplement it in `bash`.

[youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org) - parser [here](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py) (python)

[VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) - parser [here](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua) (lua)